# What are the steps to do handwritten character recognition in python? Using opencv and sci kit learn?

Tags: python, opencv, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

my project is Recognition of handwritten tamil character using python , opencv and scikit-learn.

**input file**:handwritten tamil charcter images.

**output file**:recognised character in text file.

what are the basic steps to do the project?
i know three steps,
 preprocessing , feature point extraction and classification

but,i dont know how to exactly proceed this project?

how to do the preprocessing?

where to store the training data sets images?

how to extract feature point in opencv?
how to implement this?

please help....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am working on the same project of Handwritten Arabic Character Recognition and Generation but I didn't use opencv so far. Because in opencv you have to put filters on the image and process that image and you get the processed image as a result of the same size everytime. But in Arabic there is so much variation on every character and opencv is of no use for that purpose.

For your problem, I have some suggestions and helping material too. Before starting, you have to do a lot of research about character recognition and everything you want. Read research papers of Alex Graves, he has done a lot of research on character recognition and generation. It will help you a lot.

I am using Neural Network for this purpose. Initially, it is bit difficult to understand but when you understand this, you will get everything you want. And Python is very good language for that too. I have a lot of material to learn Neural Network and how to train your dataset on that. I have some useful links too which I have shared with you below:

Alex Graves's Profile: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~graves/

Neural Network Understanding: http://nikhilbuduma.com/2014/12/29/deep-learning-in-a-nutshell/
Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q0pm3BrIUFo

Neural Network Code In Python: http://iamtrask.github.io/2015/07/12/basic-python-network/

Hope it helps you.

Thanks